# Syntax highlighter for web-code like html, php, css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, generator

I want to archive my own code examples. Therefore i need a proper view of my code including syntax highlighting. Similar as symfony framework does it on their website: http://prntscr.com/bqrmzk.

I want to know if there is a js-framework which does it without setting inline css (for e.g. colours) but classes instead. Thereby it would be easier to change the style of the elements.

To be sure that you got me right: i want same effect as on this website but without code generated with inline styles: http://markup.su/highlighter/.

Would be nice if someone could name a framework or plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) would be a good option.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for, thx.